# Chaining many to many pivot table query Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my application I have a search filter for Jobs (Model Job) which have a many to many relation with Services (Model Service). Apart from this Jobs have other characteristics as well presented as columns inside the `jobs` table as status for example.

So what I am doing is I have a multiple input form which data after submit I transform to query my database.

What I am doing is:

```
$job = new Job();
```

and then start my query with

```
$job->newQuery();
```

and start chaining wheres depending on the data from the form like

```
$job->newQuery()->where('status', 2);
```

etc.

My problem comes when the time to chain the services as a where clause. In the form the services is represented as a multiple select box so the data available to me to chain in a where clause is an array like `[1,2,5]` which represent the ids of the services the jobs I am looking for include but I do not know how to do this in Laravel.

I do have a pivot table `job_service` which has `job_id` and `service_id` etc. Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

What I have until now in the case I am searching for jobs that have the services [1,3,6] is something like

```
App\Job::where('status', '=', 2)
   ->whereHas('services', function($q) { 
        $q->whereIn('service_id',[1,3,6]); 
    }, '=',3)->get();
```

But the above returns results which have more than 3 services as well:(

Comment: It would have been better if you provided the relevant code from Models/Controllers etc instead of writing text about that. Its difficult to get the exact idea what you are doing in your app.

Comment: so you want the jobs which have status 2 and have exactly three related services and the services should be either of [1, 3, 6]......kindly confirm